# Two columns in subquery in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
```

I would like to select from `salaries` table only the rows that have period and year equal to:

```
SELECT p.period, p.years 
FROM periods p
```

I know that the simplest way would be use join, but the problem is - that in the application I can add only a clause after `WHERE`

So the solution should be:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s 
WHERE ...
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**
The result should be the same as:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
  JOIN periods p ON s.period = p.period AND s.year = p.year
```

Comment: Ì'm not sure what you are asking about, but maybe EXISTS is what you are looking for?

Comment: Add some sample table data and wanted output, and it will be much easier to assist!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use more than one column for an `IN` condition:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
where (s.year, s.period) in (select year, period from periods)
```

But Gordon's `not exists` solution is probably faster.

Comment: I like your solution too :-) Thanks. Shame that I can't accept both answers as solution :-)

Comment: I have thought a little and I must admit that your answer is the closest to my question, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the syntax doesnt work in MSSQL. Is this even possible in MSSQL?

Comment: @MavidDeyers: you need to use Gordon's answer then

Answer (score 3):

Does this work with your environment?

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM periods p
              WHERE p.period = s.period AND p.year = s.year
             )
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you please tell me how we will get p.period = s.period without joining it with salary table? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RahulTripathi when doing a subquery you can refer to the englobing query

Comment: Care to elaborate?  Full example?

Comment: This didn't work for me in SQL Server 2019 for a DELETE statement, but it did work for a SELECT statement.  The DELETE statement didn't like the correlated subquery.

Comment: For DELETE  it specifically doesn't' like the p alias so it might work if you don't use an alias on the outer table, e.g., instead of p.period try just period and remove the p and the delete statement might work.  I decided to just add an identity column and eliminate the need for multiple column correlated subquery joins.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount FROM salaries s
where s.period in (select period from periods)
and s.year in (select year from periods)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- I thought if there are more than one period or year then it would be unnecessary, (*but I suspect that I am not in the right direction*). Was curious to know about Gordon's query?

Comment: The `IN` operator will only consider distinct values to begin with, so there is no need to apply the `distinct` there

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Yes, got that. Thanks

Comment: This is not OK for me, because if I would have in salaries table period 12/2014 and in periods table periods 11/2014 and 12/2013 - it will match, but it shouldn't

Comment: @robson:- And why you are avoing the use of JOINS?

Comment: Because in this case I can add clause only after WHERE. Joins are before.

Comment: This solution actually isn't quite correct. The other solutions will only return rows where there is a period and year match in the same row of the periods table. This solution will return rows where there's a match of period in any row and a match of year in any row; they don't have to be in the same row in the periods table.