# MSSQL - checking two columns at once in a where-clause

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following oracle syntax which allows me to use two columns in an IN statement ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255010/two-columns-in-subquery-in-where-clause)). Unfortunately, this statement is not compatible with MSSQL:

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
where (s.year, s.period) in (select year, period from periods)
```

I found a solution by concatenating both columns. However, I wonder if there is not a more professional solution?

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
where (s.year + ' ' + s.period) in (select year + ' ' + period from periods)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WHERE EXISTS for this.

```
SELECT s.period, s.year, s.amount 
FROM salaries s
where exists (
    SELECT *
    from periods
    where year = s.year and period = s.period
)
```

Comment: i got some joins in the main query and the exists-statement is way unfortunately slower then the concatenation. :/

Comment: That's probably unrelated to this, but hard to tell without seeing the whole query. The main reason why concatenating is a bad idea, is that indexes will be useless. You might for example try to speed up your query by creating an index on the year + period columns in the Salaries table (assuming that is the biggest table). But with the concatenation it will not use the index in any case, because you are not using the exact columns. You might want to take a look at the execution plan and see what is exactly happening. Caching could be another reason that the concatenation is faster.

Comment: thanks for the helpful explanation. I found out that a DISTINCT was the main culprit in the main select statement. The EXISTS-Condition is now as fast as the CONCAT-IN-Clause. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, distinct requires a sort of your data, so that makes it really slow most of the  times... Now some index tuning and the Exists might actually be faster :)

Answer (score 2):

In MS SQL, you can use where exists method, which is more efficient.

```
SELECT 
    s.period
    , s.year
    , s.amount 
FROM salaries s
where exists(
    select year, period from periods p where s.year = p.year and s.period = p.period
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code will use parallel processing to eliminate records those doesn't exist in [periods] table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.[period]
      ,s.[year]
      ,s.amount 
FROM salaries s
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT * 
 FROM [periods]
 WHERE [year] = s.[year]
 AND [period] = s.[period]
)Res1
```