# Multiple columns in where clause SQL

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I was wondering about the efficiency of a couple of different queries. The task is to pull multiple tables together that must be equal from multiple columns different. I am curious about what is the best way to approach this from an efficiency standpoint.

I have already checked this out, but it doesn't say anything about multiple column where clauses
[SQL WHERE.. IN clause multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns/54389589#54389589)

and this solution shows doesn't comment on the efficiency or best practices of the solution, and doesn't include a solution where the final query is a join from the two tables
[Two columns in subquery in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255010/two-columns-in-subquery-in-where-clause)

```
select ID, col1, col2, col3 
from table1 a
left join 
    (select ID, col1, col2, col3 from table2) b on a.col1 = b.col1
where a.col2 = b.col2
  and a.col3 = b.col3
```

or

```
select ID, col1, col2, col3 
from table1 a
left join 
    (select ID, col1, col2, col3
     from table2) b on a.col1 = b.col1
                    and a.col2 = b.col2
                    and a.col3 = b.col3
```

Comment: You should be using the second version, because everything in the `ON` clause relates to the logic in the join.

Comment: Your two queries do different things.  You should start by using the query that does what you really intend.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do a join on a sub-select.  You were very close on the second sample query.  Because of the join based on 3 columns, I would make sure that the second table also has a single index using all 3 columns for optimal performance.  Ex: `Index on ( col1, col2, col3 )`, and not 3 individual indexes, one for each column.

Also, try not to use aliases like a, b, c, unless it really correlates to the name of your table like "Accounts a", "Business b", "Customers c".  Use an alias on your table references such as the abbreviation more closely matches its source.

```
select 
      t1.ID, 
      t1.col1, 
      t1.col2, 
      t1.col3,
      t2.WhatColumnFromSecondTable,
      t2.AnotherColumnFromTable2,
      t2.AnythingElse
   from 
      table1 t1
         left join table2 t2
            on t1.col1 = t2.col1
           and t1.col2 = t2.col2
           and t1.col3 = t2.col3
```

Then, if you are only looking for specific things within, you would add a WHERE clause to further filter your data down.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I was told multiple joins is slower in general and hence thought that multiple where statements would be easier, and was told to use a union, but can't find anything that validates this

Comment: Also, bear in mind that "efficiency" in this context is _highly_ dependent on what indices have been defined on the table. If the columns on which you're joining aren't covered by indices, then you're going to get a poor execution plan.

Comment: I cannot change any of the indices since it is a protected table and I don't have that access. Is there really nothing at the query level that I can do to make it more efficient?

Comment: In that case, would it be better to do a where statement? Since the other three aren't covered by indices, I can join on one, and further filter out the other columns in the where statement.

Comment: @Frank_Sma, even if one of the indexes is on one of the columns, that will help the performance.  If it is a query that will be commonly used on regular basis, you might ask if the DB admin CAN add the index for efficiency purposes.  You are not changing the table, nor the data, just adding an index which optimizes the querying OF the data.